# TypeError: Object (…) is not a function in react & js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I have this code, but for some reason, it is failing with the error:

```
TypeError: Object(…) is not a function
```

and it is saying it is happening on line 70, which is this:

```
export default withAuthentication(App)
```

here's my code for this page which imports packages, the code, and then at the end will export:

```
 import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
//import 'antd/dist/antd.css'
// (loading styles with with react-app-rewired / fixBabelImports / addLessLoader) to get overrides on colors and fonts

import * as routes from './routes'

import withAuthentication from './withAuthentication'
import AuthUserContext from './AuthUserContext'

import SignUpPage from './pages/SignUpPage'
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage'
import PasswordForgetPage from './pages/PasswordForgetPage'
import MainPage from './pages/MainPage'
import NewClientPage from './pages/NewClientPage'
import EditClientPage from './pages/EditClientPage'
import NewEstimatePage from './pages/NewEstimatePage'
import EditEstimatePage from './pages/EditEstimatePage'
import TestPage from './pages/TestPage'
import UserProfileContent from './components/UserProfileContent'
import StripeApp from './Stripepayment/StripeApp'
import NameRegistration from './components/NameField'
// import App from './App.js'

const App = ({ authUser }) => {
  return <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    { authUser => authUser
      ? <LoggedInApp authUser={authUser}/>
      : <NotLoggedInApp />
    }
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
}



const NotLoggedInApp = () =>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={LoginPage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={SignUpPage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForgetPage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.NAMEREGISTER} component={NameRegistration} />
    <Route exact path={routes.STRIPEAPP} component={StripeApp} />
    <LoginPage />
  </Switch>

const TabRoute = ({ path }) =>
  <Route exact path={path} render={(props) => <MainPage showTab={path} {...props} />} />

const LoggedInApp = ({ authUser }) =>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={routes.SIGN_IN} component={LoginPage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.NEWCLIENT} component={NewClientPage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.EDITCLIENT + '/:id'} render={(props) => <EditClientPage clientId={props.match.params.id} />}/>
    <Route exact path={routes.NEWESTIMATE} component={NewEstimatePage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.EDITESTIMATE + '/:id'} render={(props) => <EditEstimatePage estimateId={props.match.params.id} />}/>
    <Route exact path={routes.TEST} component={TestPage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForgetPage} />
    <Route exact path={routes.CLIENTS + '/:id'} render={(props) => <MainPage showTab={routes.CLIENTS} {...props} />} />
    <Route exact path={routes.ESTIMATES + '/:id'} render={(props) => <MainPage showTab={routes.ESTIMATES} {...props} />} />
    <Route exact path={routes.JOBS + '/:id'} render={(props) => <MainPage showTab={routes.JOBS} {...props} />} />
    
    
    <TabRoute path={routes.CLIENTS} />
    <TabRoute path={routes.ESTIMATES} />
    <TabRoute path={routes.JOBS} />
    <TabRoute exact path={routes.PROFILE} component={UserProfileContent}/>
    <Redirect to={routes.CLIENTS} />
  </Switch>


export default withAuthentication(App)
```

Comment: Your code includes no semicolons, so you're falling victim to the behavior of automatic semicolon insertion somewhere.

Comment: so should I put semicolons after every package I import then?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where the parser is getting confused. The error you get is probably a line or two *after* the place(s) you need semicolons.

Comment: It's a matter of personal style; some people say don't bother, but then this happens and it's confusing. Personally I *always* use semicolons between statements.

Comment: @Pointy it might also be failing in the compiled code. It's extremely annoying. Had an issue once where *nothing* worked because a single file was missing a single semi-colon at exactly the correct place for the bindler to produce code that was completely mangled.

Comment: it could happen that "withAuthentication" actually is not a function but an object, but also could be due to this old react issue: [link](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14484)